# CSS element doesn't show up in Chrome, but does on Firefox

Tags: css

I'm very new to all of this CSS business, so please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. I'm using the 960.gz grid system to create a site at www.locodingo.com

I'm having an issue getting a light grey box (adBox in my CSS code) to show up on the right side of my website in Chrome underneath my menu, but it loads just fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer. I've messed with what seems like pretty much every variable but just can't get it to show. Please help!

```
* {
    font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:black;
}

#header {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    height:90px;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:absolute;
}

#header #logo {
    height:80px;
    padding:5px;

}

#nav li {
    color:#F58535;
    background-color:white;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:-99px;
    right:0px;
    text-align:left;
    display:inline;
    padding:7px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:15px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

#nav2 li {
    color:#6ABD50;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    top:32px;
    padding:7px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    right:10px;
}

#nav li:hover {
    background-color:#F58535;
    color:white;
}

#nav2 li:hover {
    background-color:#6ABD50;
    color:white;
}

#adsBox {
    height:250px;
    background-color:#F2F3F3;
    margin-top: 50px;
    clear:right;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#adsBox p {
    margin:5px;
    text-align:justify;
}

#footer {
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
    color:#F58535;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
    clear:both;
}

bodyText{
    right:122px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    color:red;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: where is the html code?

Comment: which tag you are trying to apply this style?

Comment: Just a tip of advice, always dev it on GC. It will save you time in cross browse testing

Comment: `bodyText` is it a class/ID?

Comment: please make a JSFiddle if possible. Also, there are multiple minor problems in your CSS.

Comment: MrBearAndBeer, sorry for not including the HTML code. I was flustered and clearly not thinking straight when I posted this.

Drixson, what is GC? Is that a website or program? Also, bodyText was the last thing I was working on. I did notice I needed to add a pound sign there since it was an ID. In this case it was inconsequential to the issue I was having.

Raptor, I will do that next time I have an issue. And, I'd be happy to hear about these minor problems. I've only been messing with this stuff for a few days so most everything you teach me will be valuable new knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="container_12 clearfix">
        <div id="header" class="grid_12">
            <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"/>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>Contact Us</li>
                    <li>Message Board</li>
                    <li>Opinion</li>
                    <li>Articles</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav2">
        <ul>
            <span><li>Cosplay</li></span>
            <span><li>Tattoos</li></span>
            <span><li>Music/Art</li></span>
            <span><li>Recipes</li></span>
        </ul>
    </div>   
    <div class="container_12 clearfix">
       <div id="bodyText" class="grid_8"><p>Just safdsfdadfafdfdome random stuff here.ust safdsfdadfafdfdome random stufust safdsfdadfafdfdome random stufust safdsfdadfafdfdome random stufust safdsfdadfafdfdome random stufust safdsfdadfafdfdome random stufust safdsfdadfafdfdome random stuf adggdadgsagddgsdsgagsd</p></div>

        <div id="adsBox" class="grid_4"><p>Test text here est text hereTest text here est text hereTest text here est text hereTest text here est text hereTest text here est text hereTest text here est text hereTest text here est text hereTest text here est text here</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have AdBlockPlus or any kind of adblocker extension in Chrome? If so, it's probably hiding that block based on its id.

Comment: Oh my God. Thank you so much! It does work without AdBlockPlus! And, yes, apparently it is because the name of the div container contained the word "ads". You learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

jack was able to answer my issue for me. It was indeed AdBlockPlus blocking the div container because it was called "adsBox" and contained the word "ads". I feel pretty stupid - I guessthis is just one of those stupid little things I've got to learn about on my journey.

So, for future reference - don't name any container with the word "ads" in it.

Thank all of you for helping me out. Each and every one of you had valuable information that I'll be able to use.